# Where would I be able to obtain or purchase GeoJSON data for Manhattan submarkets?

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

GeoJSON data contains arrays of coordinates that create polylines (like borders). You can find geoJSON data for the 50 U.S. state borders, for example. I would like proper geoJSON data for this: https://www.scribblemaps.com/create/#/id=HfPjzTz28R&lat=40.76084989&lng=-73.98615251&z=14&t=mbb_road

Does anyone know where I would find or commission this? It's going into a Kotlin-based web endpoint that creates maps.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [open data portal for NYC](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/browse).  For example, the [NYC borough boundaries GIS data](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Borough-Boundaries/tqmj-j8zm).

Answer (score 2):

If by “submarket” you just mean “neighborhood” then there are plenty of open sources

For example: 
https://github.com/veltman/snd3/blob/master/data/nyc-neighborhoods.geo.json